# Multiple flush in same EJB transaction causing the changes of the first flush disappear

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, sql-update, flush

I have a container managed transactions and in one method which has an entity manager associated to that transaction . Tables that i have is a parent table and an association for an another table which contains the children of the parent table.

In same session i do the following items in the sequence mentioned below :
Initially in the session we will not have the parent object or the child object .But parent object will be there in the DB and children will be added in the method that we are interested in .

1. I get the parent object from the DB in the session so this parent
   object will be in the session.
2. I create a new child record and associate this child to the parent table, since the parent is part of the session hibernate must take care of adding the child record in the child table correct ??
3. Then i will perform a flush at this point.
4. Again i will add a new child to the collection of the parent
5. As said before hibernate must take care of adding it rite ?
6. I am performing the flush again now .
7. At the end of the EJB transaction the hibernate will generate all the other sql statements.

After performing these operations i see that in the DB only the child that is added second time is getting associated to the parent table.But for the first child entry is present but the parent association is not getting set .

If i remove the flush in between adding the children both the children are getting correctly associated to the parent .Flush is causing an issue here , but i have to use flush here at any cost because take into consideration i am associating 100 children once shot then perform a flush and later i will associate another 10 children and then do a flush only the last 10 children are associated to the parent all others are in orphan stage .This is causing a issue for me !:(

Please comment back on how to solve this issue .Should i perform some other operations like update or saveOrUpdate before the flush ?

THE algorithm is here please find it :
Since the code is big and long i will be posting the algorithm of how the operation is performed
Assume i have 2 tables one for the parent named PARENT and the other for the child named CHILD \ 
And the child entity is extended from the parent entity
Assume that initially i have only one parent record in the DB and there is no CHILD records in the child table
There is a bidirectional link between the child and the parent one-to-many and vice verse.
At the start of the transaction i ll get the parent data frm the DB so that the parent gets associated to the Persistence Context .
Now assume i am creating a new POGO object of the child and fill its data. Assume that i will create 20 such objects and then associate both bidirectional the child to parent and parent to child.
Since the parent is in hibernate context when i associate it to child hibernate will take care of creating and making the link .
Now assume i do a flush on the session context .
Next i create 10 more POGO objects of the child and do the same association to parent , and carry out a flush again.

after the end of transaction when i check the DB i see that the first 20 entries are there in the DB but the association for them to parent is absent. But for the last added 10 Child objects both the entries and the association for the parent is there.

When i remove the flush in between adding the child between 20- and 10 i see that all the 30 are correctly getting associated. I want to know why the flush is causing the problem.

Comment: Please include relevant code: Annotations, hbm.xml, ... Is it a bi-directional ManyToOne perhaps? Do you have cascade defined?

Comment: Hi @greyfairer there is a bi-directional one to many mapping from the parent to the children and vice versa.and the cascasde type is all

Answer (score 0):

You need to take special care if you use a bi-directional relation as described in the hibernate reference:

```
<class name="Person">
 <id name="id" column="personId">
     <generator class="native"/>
 </id>
 <many-to-one name="address"          column="addressId"         not-null="true"/>
</class> 
<class name="Address">
 <id name="id" column="addressId">
     <generator class="native"/>
 </id>
 <set name="people" inverse="true">
     <key column="addressId"/>
     <one-to-many class="Person"/>
 </set>
</class>
```

In this case, if you add a person to address.people, but person.address is null, hibernate will not save the person, because the address.people relation is inverse="true".

You need to set both directions of the relation for hibernate to save it correctly:

```
public void addPerson(Person person) {
    person.setAddress(this);
    this.people.add(person);
}
```

See [1.2.6 Working bi-directional links](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-usingbidir) in the hibernate tutorial.

Comment: Hi @greyfairer thanks for the above comment and info . since i had bi-directional assosiation . When i am adding to one side of the assosiation i am making sure that the other side also same update is pushed :( but still the issue is there. I will post my code so that u can get more idea.

Comment: please find the algorithm in the question itself i have edited it .

Comment: Sorry, mate, you need to paste the essential parts of the code. Use the {} button to markup the code, stackoverflow will put a scroll bar next to it, if it's too long.

If you say: 'the child extends the parent', there are many ways to to do this wrong...

Did you try Session.save(child) for every child? That could be a quick (but dirty) workaround.